# How to get local to spring boot to localize messages?

Tags: spring

How do i get the local of the user so that i can send proper localized message in response pdf file? Autowiring not working properly

```
@Autowire
private final Local local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Local in the controller

```
@Controller
public ResponseEntity controllerMethod(Locale locale) {

}
```